# Eclipse SVNKit cannot read project SVN after using TortoiseSVN Merge on Windows

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, subversive, svnkit

I've just used Tortoise SVN to merge a branch to the trunk on Windows because doing so in Eclipse was causing all sorts of problems. I have managed to get all the changes in and sort out the conflicts.

However when I open Eclipse to test that the merge has worked it doesn't connect to the SVN for the project.

I'm not totally sure how to sort this issue out, so if anyone has any experience here it would be handy.

I'm using SVNKit 1.2.2 and Subversive in Eclipse.
Then TortoiseSVN 1.6.14 for Windows (64-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that SVNKit 1.2.2 does not support [SVN 1.6 format](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html), cause the working copy format differs. You have to update your connection in Eclipse to get it working.